# Execute Query on Node.js Using Express and Form Input Submit

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, input

I apologize if this has been asked before, if it has please send me in that direction.

I have a node.js app using express. I want to click on a button (form input submit) on the client side and have it run a query on the server side. I am not looking for the query to post or put, I want it to execute a Neo4j query that generates a csv file. The query is not the issue, the query works, the issue is getting the click of a button (form input submit) on client side to run the query on the server side. Here is what I've tried that does not work...

**index.ejs**

```
<form method="post" action="/barrelsankeycsv">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="RunQueryGenCSV">
</form>
```

...

**server.js**

```
app.post('/barrelsankeycsv', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  try {
    const result = await session.run('run neo4j query that generates csv file');
    if (result) {
      res.redirect('/');
      session.close();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Something went wrong", e);
  };
});
```

What am I doing wrong? I've also tried app.all but that doesn't work either. If there is a better way to go about this, I'm all ears.

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you show server console log?

Comment: You mean to show any errors logged? If so, it's not logging any errors to show.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use cURL or Postman to send a POST request to express server. If that works, the problem is on frontend. But I think `index.ejs` has no problem from what I see.
2. Add the following code before routing:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

Comment: Thanks @bravemaster, I am successfully sending POST GET PUT DELETE from other parts of my app (index.ejs to server.js), and I added the ```...express.urlencoded...``` as you suggested, but it's still not working.

Comment: Thank you again @bravemaster, in the end the error was mine. I had the <form> code seen above nested inside another <form> and that prohibited any action. So in the end I'm marking your comment as 'Helpful' as you confirmed there appeared to be nothing wrong with my code.

Comment: @Redlink Thanks. Happy to help :)